# How to compare textbox value if exist in 2d array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this code and I need to compare the user input and the hardcoded 2d array. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks!

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $array = array
        ( 
               0=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Art', 
                      'password'=>'p@ssw0rd',
                      'user_id'=>'1'              
                    ),
               1=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Berto',
                      'password'=>'1234',
                      'user_id'=>'2'
                    ),
               2=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Carrie',
                      'password'=>'5678',
                      'user_id'=>'3'
                    ),
               3=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Dino',
                      'password'=>'qwer',
                      'user_id'=>'4'
                    ),
               4=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Ely',
                      'password'=>'asdf',
                      'user_id'=>'5'
                    )
             ); 
    if(in_array($_POST['user'], $users))
    {
       $key = array_search($_POST['user'], $users);
```

I want to match the username if it exist through the 2d array. It is also the same for the password field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined your array name as $array but using $users in the in_array().

Anyways, suppose you use the correct name, you can match like this:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $item)
{
if ($item['username'] === $_POST['user'] && 
    $item['password'] === $_POST['password'])   
    return $key;

return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It worked for me. I got an additional question. How will I be able to have a pop message that will display its corresponding user_id? @Asif

Comment: You're welcome. If you think the answer is appropriate then you have to mark it as Answer.

By pop you mean to display the user_id? you can use the returned $key value to access the array item and then user_id:

`echo $users[$key]['user_id'];`

or inside the if condition, just before return $key you can echo the user_id value:

...
`echo $item['user_id']
return $key;`
...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through foreach loop

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
  if($value['username'] == $_POST['user'] && $value['password'] == $_POST['pwd'])
  {
      // do whatever you want to do here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchForValue($fkey, $uvalue, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val[$fkey] == $uvalue) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

call it like this

```
$id = searchForValue('username', $_POST['user'], $<yourarray>);
```

in case of password search

```
$id = searchForValue('password', $_POST['pass'], $<yourarray>);
```

Comment: Hi, an additional question. I need to have a pop up message that will display their corresponding user_id. How will I do this? Thanks!

Comment: if my above answer has helped you solve the question, then could you please accept it. As for the new question the proper way would be to ask a new question so that everybody will be able to contribute.